# What difference between active federation and passive federation in ADFS?

Tags: adfs

I am new in ADFS. Actually I dont know what is Active or passive federation and also don't know the difference between them,Can Anybody help me on this?

Thanks in advance !!!...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passive uses the browser - to do redirects etc. Protocol is WS-Federation. User is asked to log-on via a flow.

Active uses a web service - protocol is WS-Trust. It's essentially "headless". User normally doesn't actively log-on - credentials may be part of the web service.

Comment: any reference implementation samples?

Comment: Have a poke around http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/. Lots of passive e.g. https://github.com/AzureADSamples but WCF has been superseded by Web API.